# Failed to extract specific tables from web onto spreadsheet in Excel VBA (Mac)

Tags: excel, vba, macos

Basically, I have the following program, which allow me to obtain stock prices of a particular stock, say "700" in the below example.The stock prices appear in a particular table on the webpage. In a PC computer, I was able to use

`.WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables`

`.WebTables = "4"`

to pick out the specific tables that I want from the webpage. However on a mac, I could not do that and I ran into this `run-time error 438 : object doesn't support this property or method`. This is really annoying. So I removed those 2 lines from the code. But the problem is that: I could not extract the particular stock prices table from the web now. Can anyone show me how I can overcome this ?

```
Sub getStockDataTest()
    getGoogleStockHistory 700

End Sub


Sub getGoogleStockHistory(gInt As Long)
      'load google stock hisotry

    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="URL;https://www.google.com.hk/finance/historical?q=HKG%3A" & Format(gInt, "0000") & "&num=200", Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Query").[A1])
        .Name = "WebQuery"
        .RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells
        .SaveData = True
        .Refresh
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 7):

**Office 2011 for Mac**

Looking about, is seems that the .WebTables property is either a [VBA 6](http://www.realgeek.com/forums/querytable-properties-364458.html) implementation or something that [only works on IE](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Software/Office_Productivity/Office_Suites/MS_Office/Excel/Q_26721716.html)

**Possible workaround**

Import everything on a hidden sheet and then copy and paste across the relevant section since layout should be fairly consistent for different stock types

---

**General Guidance**

**Creating a web query**

For Mac, you need to create a web query file in order to retrieve the web contents. Microsoft have produced a how-to that should help you: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/274787

**Referencing specific tables to import**

You can specify which table to select using the Selection parameter. Here is an example of a webquery built using Excel 2013 Windows.

```
WEB
1
https://www.google.com.hk/finance/historical?q=HKG%3A0005&num=200#
num=200&q=["stock","stock sym"]

Selection=4
Formatting=None
PreFormattedTextToColumns=True
ConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne=True
SingleBlockTextImport=False
DisableDateRecognition=False
DisableRedirections=False
```

**Using an .iqy file**

With .iqy file you can then load it using "FINDER;C:\folderstructure\queryname.iqy" instead of using URL:

```
Sub example()
    Workbooks("Book6").Connections.AddFromFile _
        "C:\Users\slocke\Desktop\hkquery.iqy"
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "FINDER;C:\Users\slocke\Desktop\hkquery.iqy", Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
        .CommandType = 0
        .Name = "hkquery"
        .WebTables = "4"
    End With
End Sub
```

**Using the .iqy file with a changing value**

I have added an iqy and workbook with some basic vba in for importing and updating the table based on a text box location for the parameter you are changing.

You can take this further to amend your loop statement to insert the value or you could probably update it in the VBA directly but I wanted to provide a simpler way of changing the table to make it more visual.
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/40423572/SO%20items/hkexample.xlsm
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/40423572/SO%20items/hkquery.iqy

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Well, I did that already. But how to get specific tables from a webpage? The web query mentioned in your  link only talks about how to create a web query file but it doesn't tell me how to EXTRACT specific tables from a webpage.

Comment: I tried the following code, which is very similar to yours except the URL. `WEB
1
https://www.google.com.hk/finance/historical?q=HKG%3A0005&num=200

Selection=4
Formatting=None
PreFormattedTextToColumns=True
ConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne=True
SingleBlockTextImport=False
DisableDateRecognition=False
DisableRedirections=False`
However, no matter what value I set the "selection = ", it still gives me some unneccessary data at the top of the spreadsheet. Do you understand why this is happening ?

Comment: I've added some samples to dropbox which have parameterisation included - could you take a look and see how they work for you? I don't have a Mac or a copy of the workbook to check specifics for you so I've built a MWE

Comment: the problem is that Mac Excel VBA 2011 doesn't support query tables and `webtables = "4"` will give rise to error in mac VBA.

Comment: Looking at some of the msdn forum posts it looks like it is because vba5 does not support the property and the mac office runs off vba5 not vba6.  Unfortunately I can't access any of the documentation because they are mac2 links.

Comment: Steph - I was curious if its possible to navigate to a website, enter data in a text box and click a link in Mac Excel 2011.  Thanks

Comment: @Mutuelinvestor not sure in mac but I have seen vba for logging in to site and then getting table which is a similar concept. I recommend asking a new Q for the info to go against